# Place Image in the center of a div

Tags: html, css

I would love to put the images in logos related to the center of the boxes.

https://pnghunter.com/logo/acura-nsx-gray/

How can I affect this?

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 3):

Add css properties `display: block; margin: 0 auto` to the images.

You can also use flexbox. Add the following css properties -

`display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use flexbox though?

Comment: Flex box works but this is simpler

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to display the image as `block` and add `auto` margin to both sides (left & right).

```css
.container {
   background-color: gray;
   padding: 30px 0;
}

img {
   width: 50%;
   
   /* This will do the trick */
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-acura-nsx-graycarvehicletransportautocars-561521125226tokdl.png" alt="Car">
</div>
```

Alternative: Use `flexbox`. Will not be as robust as auto-margins due to [many bugs](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) still present in IE. However, if the parent's height is set, this will also center vertically.

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 30px 0;

  /* Here comes the magic */
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  
}

img {
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-acura-nsx-graycarvehicletransportautocars-561521125226tokdl.png" alt="Car">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

put this css rules...

```
.logo__container{
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use flexbox for this.
Add the following css to the containers (logo__container):

```
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; //horizontal
    align-items: center; //vertical
```

Comment: It's easier to use "display: block and margin: 0 auto". Lesser attributes will be better.

Comment: It doesn't add the vertical alignment though.

Comment: @hansololives Not sure if vertical alignment is a requirement of the OP. Note that `flexbox` is [bugged in IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). Auto-margins are safer in terms of compatibility.

Comment: But if you inspect the website he linked you can see that he already has the `display: block` and `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` on the images, so I assumed he wanted something more.

Comment: @hansololives Absolutely correct guess :) Thank you very much!